# How to extract several values from a string with regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I need to parse a string and extract substrings to a variable. The strings are not the same. Examples and expected results:

```
string 1 (no "NAME" pattern): "RB2 F 27/0/31 0/32, R8 28/31/120 2/0/2"
result 1 (save "as is"): "RB2 F 27/0/31 0/32, R8 28/31/120 2/0/2"

string 2 (comma separated "<key>:<value>" pairs): "TYPE :ABC,NAME: AB.DE,DESC:10/10/5:2,COMMENT: , ID:123"
result 2 (extracted comma separated "<key>=<value>" substrings): "TYPE=ABC","NAME=AB.DE","DESC=10/10/5:2","COMMENT=","ID=123"

string 3: "ID:123, NAME:CDE,DESC:10-10/5:2"
result 3: "ID=123","NAME:CDE","DESC=10-10/5:2"
```

Playing with "re.compile" and "split" but can't find a regex suitable for all the mentioned examples.

Comment: Why "NAME:CDE" not converted to "NAME=CDE"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below regex to find key value pairs with `findall()`. then join them with `=`

```regex
([a-zA-Z ]+):(.*?)(?:,|$)
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/ZRi0HP/1)

**Sample program**

```py
import re

inputs=["RB2 F 27/0/31 0/32, R8 28/31/120 2/0/2",
"TYPE :ABC,NAME: AB.DE,DESC:10/10/5:2,COMMENT: , ID:123",
"ID:123, NAME:CDE,DESC:10-10/5:2"]

output=[]
for line in inputs:
    output.append([a+'='+b for a,b in re.findall("([a-zA-Z ]+):(.*?)(?:,|$)",line)] or line)
    
print(output)
```

**Output**

```py
[
 'RB2 F 27/0/31 0/32, R8 28/31/120 2/0/2',
 ['TYPE =ABC', 'NAME= AB.DE', 'DESC=10/10/5:2', 'COMMENT= ', ' ID=123'],
 ['ID=123', ' NAME=CDE', 'DESC=10-10/5:2']
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this if it's okay to assume that there won't be a ':' in the key.

```
if ':' in string:
    string = string.replace(' ', '')
    string = string.split(',')
    for (i, word) in enumerate(string):
        string[i] = word.replace(':', '=', 1)
```